# pyparsing: how to get token location?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have a simple `pyparsing` grammar that matches numbers separated by spaces:

```
from pyparsing import *
NUMBER = Word( nums )
STATEMENT = ZeroOrMore( NUMBER )
print( STATEMENT.parseString( "1 2 34" ) )
```

Given `1 2 34` test string it returns 3 strings that are parsed tokens. But how do I find the location of each token in the original string? I need it for "kind of" syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this parse action to NUMBER:

```
NUMBER.setParseAction(lambda locn,tokens: (locn,tokens[0]))
```

Parse actions can be passed the tokens that were parsed for a given expression, the location of the parse, and the original string. You can pass functions to `setParseAction` with any of these signatures:

```
fn()
fn(tokens)
fn(locn,tokens)
fn(srctring,locn,tokens)
```

For your needs, all you need is the location and the parsed tokens.

After adding this parse action, your parsed results now look like:

```
[(0, '1'), (2, '2'), (4, '34')]
```

**EDIT:**

Since my original answer to this post, I've added to pyparsing the `locatedExpr` helper, which will give both the starting and ending location for a particular expression. Now this can be written simply as:

```
NUMBER = locatedExpr(Word(nums))
```

Here is the full script/output:

```
>>> from pyparsing import *
... NUMBER = locatedExpr(Word( nums ))
... STATEMENT = ZeroOrMore( NUMBER )
... print( STATEMENT.parseString( "1 2 34" ).dump() )

[[0, '1', 1], [2, '2', 3], [4, '34', 6]]
[0]:
  [0, '1', 1]
  - locn_end: 1
  - locn_start: 0
  - value: '1'
[1]:
  [2, '2', 3]
  - locn_end: 3
  - locn_start: 2
  - value: '2'
[2]:
  [4, '34', 6]
  - locn_end: 6
  - locn_start: 4
  - value: '34'
```

Comment: Hi Paul, when I use this method to get tokens, the token is placed first in the output, so if I had a named token (i.e. Word("foo")), then when I get "results.foo", I end up getting the column number.  Is there a way I can maintain named results but still get the column number?

Comment: I figured it out: ```ELEMENT.setParseAction(lambda locn, tokens: (tokens[0], locn))
```  --> this puts the tokens first and the position last

Comment: I can't figure out how to reach the position value via the named range; is this possible?  @PaulMcG

Comment: @skelliam - Would you mind posting this as a new question? I'm not looking for racking up more rep :), it just gives me (and others) more room for posting answers with sample code and description. (Plus SO doesn't like long discussion threads in comments.)

Comment: I think I got it figured out, as an example:  ```define = pound + pp.Literal("define").setParseAction(lambda locn, tokens: {'pos':locn, 'val':tokens[0]})```  I can still post a new question in case there is a better way.

Comment: posted new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53182411/get-token-position-in-string-with-pyparsing-using-named-values

Comment: But it only gives the starting position, right? But what about the end-position?

Comment: Oh, I see, the end-position would be the start position + `len(returned_token)`. Might be worth mentioning in the answer, it's not an obvious thing.

Comment: @Hi-Angel - I've updated my answer to reflect a newer feature in pyparsing that makes this much easier.