# Get token position in string with pyparsing, using named values

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm trying to get the token position in the string when using pyparsing.  I want to report the location of an include guard issue in C files:

```
import pyparsing as pp

m = None
n = None

#a sample C header file
lines = "\
#ifndef HEADER_FILE_H\n\
#define HEADER_FILE_H 1\n\
\n\
\n\
/* code is here */\n\
\n\
#endif /* HEADER_FILE_H */\
"

LBRACE,RBRACE,LBRACK,RBRACK,LT,GT,LPAREN,RPAREN,DQ,SEMI = map(pp.Suppress,'{}[]<>()";')
CIDENT = pp.Word(pp.alphanums + "_")  #any C identifier
LCOMMENT = pp.Suppress("/*")
RCOMMENT = pp.Suppress("*/")

last_line = lines.split("\n")[-1]  #get last line

pound = pp.Literal("#") + pp.Suppress(pp.Optional(pp.White(" \t")))
ifndef = pound + pp.Literal("ifndef")
ifnotdefined = pound + pp.Literal("if") + pp.Literal("!defined")
define = pound + pp.Literal("define")
endif = pound + pp.Literal("endif")
comment = pp.Optional(LCOMMENT + CIDENT("guardname_endif") + RCOMMENT)("guard_end_comment")

includeguardifndef = pp.Or([ifndef, ifnotdefined]) + pp.Optional(LPAREN) + CIDENT("guardname_ifndef_val") + pp.Optional(RPAREN)
includeguard = define + CIDENT("guardname_define_val") + pp.Optional(pp.Literal("1")("guard_is_one"))
includeguard_top = includeguardifndef + includeguard
includeguardendif = endif("includeguardendif") + comment

try:
   m = includeguard_top.parseString(lines)
except pp.ParseException:
   pass

try:
   n = includeguardendif.parseString(last_line)
except pp.ParseException:
   pass

print(m)
print(n)
```

Now when I get my match "m", I can get m.guardname_define_value, and ultimately I want to get something like m.guardname_define_value.pos, which is the position of the match in "lines".

I arrived at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15295651/pyparsing-how-to-get-token-location) which gets me nearly there, but I can't figure out how to still get named ranges with the tokens?  I don't want to use magic numbers to get the position at the end of the match.

I'm no stranger to regex, but I'm new to pyparsing and pretty amazed with how powerful and clear it is.  Really enjoying it.  If there are suggestions on what I've done above I'll take that too.

1. Main question is getting token location w/ named result, not using magic numbers.  e.g.: I don't want to do something cryptic like `m.guardname_define_value[0][0]` to get the position
2. Do I need to try/catch for pp.ParseException like I'm doing above?  If I don't, I get an exception.  I don't really care if the match fails, I just check the result for None anyway.
3. Thinking the nestedExpr might do what I want here, but one step better, where I could automatically have it look for `#ifdef ... #endif` that magically match?  (maybe if opener is '#ifdef' and closer is '#endif'?)
4. What is the proper way of saying "search for anything" without being too greedy?  i.e. this regex:  `".*(FOO).*"` would consume and discard anything until it found and captured FOO, then consume and discard anything after it, I'm having a hard time replicating that.

Thank you.

Comment: 1. Generally, it is not necessary to include `White` elements in your grammar, pyparsing will implicitly skip whitespace. 2. Your code sample does not run, you have left some bits out, like LCOMMENT and RCOMMENT. (You might also look at some of the pre-defined comment expressions, like `cStyleComment` and `cppStyleComment`) 3. Could you include some of the text you are trying to parse?  4. "Search for anything" might be handled using SkipTo, not sure what you are parsing. 5. Glad to hear that your pyparsing experience is positive, despite some challenges!

Comment: Thanks @PaulMcG, I've updated with a more complete example that should run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your sample code, with some slight modifications. (I really dislike backslashes, and you might find working with triple quotes easier on the eyes when embedding text samples in your scripts.) Notably, I'm showing the use of `locatedExpr`. It may be what you really wanted to see. Also, see this SO question: [Pyparsing: get token location in results name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706631/pyparsing-get-token-location-in-results-name/18709082#18709082)

```
import pyparsing as pp

#a sample C header file
lines = """
#ifndef HEADER_FILE_H
#define HEADER_FILE_H 1


/* code is here */

#endif /* HEADER_FILE_H */
"""

LBRACE,RBRACE,LBRACK,RBRACK,LT,GT,LPAREN,RPAREN,DQ,SEMI = map(pp.Suppress,'{}[]<>()";')
CIDENT = pp.Word(pp.alphas + "_", pp.alphanums + "_")  #any C identifier
LCOMMENT = pp.Suppress("/*")
RCOMMENT = pp.Suppress("*/")


def make_directive(s, pound=pp.Literal("#")):
    return pp.Combine(pound + s, adjacent=False)

ifndef = make_directive("ifndef")
ifnotdefined = make_directive("if") + pp.Literal("!defined")
define = make_directive("define")
endif = make_directive("endif")

comment = pp.Optional(LCOMMENT
                      + CIDENT("guardname_endif") 
                      + RCOMMENT)("guard_end_comment")


includeguardifndef = ((ifndef | ifnotdefined) 
                      + pp.Optional(LPAREN) 
                      + CIDENT("guardname_ifndef_val") 
                      + pp.Optional(RPAREN))
includeguard = (define 
                + CIDENT("guardname_define_val") 
                + pp.Optional(pp.Literal("1")("guard_is_one")))
includeguard_top = includeguardifndef + includeguard
includeguardendif = endif("includeguardendif") + comment

# parse the header
parser = includeguard_top + pp.SkipTo(includeguardendif).suppress() + includeguardendif
print(parser.parseString(lines).dump())

# parse the header, with locns
loc = pp.locatedExpr
parser = loc(includeguard_top) + pp.SkipTo(includeguardendif).suppress() + loc(includeguardendif)
print(parser.parseString(lines).dump())
```

Prints:

```
['#ifndef', 'HEADER_FILE_H', '#define', 'HEADER_FILE_H', '1', '#endif', 'HEADER_FILE_H']
- guard_end_comment: ['HEADER_FILE_H']
- guard_is_one: '1'
- guardname_define_val: 'HEADER_FILE_H'
- guardname_endif: 'HEADER_FILE_H'
- guardname_ifndef_val: 'HEADER_FILE_H'
- includeguardendif: '#endif'

[[1, '#ifndef', 'HEADER_FILE_H', '#define', 'HEADER_FILE_H', '1', 46], [69, '#endif', 'HEADER_FILE_H', 95]]
[0]:
  [1, '#ifndef', 'HEADER_FILE_H', '#define', 'HEADER_FILE_H', '1', 46]
  - guard_is_one: '1'
  - guardname_define_val: 'HEADER_FILE_H'
  - guardname_ifndef_val: 'HEADER_FILE_H'
  - locn_end: 46
  - locn_start: 1
  - value: ['#ifndef', 'HEADER_FILE_H', '#define', 'HEADER_FILE_H', '1']
[1]:
  [69, '#endif', 'HEADER_FILE_H', 95]
  - guard_end_comment: ['HEADER_FILE_H']
  - guardname_endif: 'HEADER_FILE_H'
  - includeguardendif: '#endif'
  - locn_end: 95
  - locn_start: 69
  - value: ['#endif', 'HEADER_FILE_H']
```

Comment: Thanks @PaulMcG, I've since gotten it working but I will take a close look at what you're doing here and see how I can improve what I've done!